# Sum values within 24 hours without repetition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a dataset of 3 columns - Name, date-time, value

For ex:

```
Name DateTime         value 
----------------------------
 A   1/1/2011 1:00:00   626
 A   1/1/2011 2:00:00  2311 
 B   1/1/2011 3:00:00   775 
 A   1/1/2011 4:00:00  6621 
 A   1/1/2011 5:00:00  8491 
 B   1/1/2011 6:00:00  9061 
 B   1/1/2011 7:00:00  3611 
 B   1/2/2011 4:00:00  5491 
 A   1/2/2011 5:00:00    21
```

and I want to sum the values grouped by Name and 24 hours but without repetition (if I used one row I don't want to reuse it)

Expected value:

```
Name Value 
A    2368 
B    2042 
B     549 
A       2
```

I used a `while` loop to mark the occurrences within 24 hours with unique index and it works but takes forever to run because I have big data table

Comment: 24 hours means a standard calendar day?

Comment: please do NOT use images of data, supply the data in a reusable form (text) and do NOT use external image libraries anyway.

Comment: not a calendar day but 24h - so if there is value in 23:00 i expect it to be summed with the value at 1:00 on the day after

Comment: I have adjusted my answer in response to your latest comment above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a solution: find the max value for each Name within 24h and than to check which of the dates is the first and includes the current occurrence within

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

CREATE TABLE #Temp
(
    Name varchar(128)
       ,[Date]     DATETIME
    ,[Value]   INT
);

INSERT INTO #Temp
SELECT 'A','2011-01-01 1:00:00',626
UNION ALL SELECT 'A','2011-01-01 2:00:00',231 
UNION ALL SELECT 'B','2011-01-01 3:00:00',775 
UNION ALL SELECT 'A','2011-01-01 4:00:00',662 
UNION ALL SELECT 'A','2011-01-01 5:00:00',849 
UNION ALL SELECT 'B','2011-01-01 6:00:00',906 
UNION ALL SELECT 'B','2011-01-01 7:00:00',361 
 UNION ALL SELECT 'B','2011-01-02 4:00:00',549
UNION ALL SELECT 'A','2011-01-02 5:00:00',2
  UNION ALL SELECT 'A','2011-01-03 4:00:00',1


SELECT * FROM #Temp
order by [Date];


select Name,[Date],[Value],(select max([Date]) from #temp t2
                                 where t2.Name=t1.Name and t2.[Date] between t1.[Date] and dateadd(hour,24,t1.[Date])) MaxVal
into #temp2
from #temp t1

select *,(select min(date) from #temp2 t2 where t1.[Date] between t2.[Date] and t2.MaxVal and t1.Name=t2.Name ) MinOfMax
into #temp3
from #temp2 t1


select Name,sum(value)
from #temp3
group by  Name,MinOfMax
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this way

```
select Name,SUM(Value) from Tblname group by Name,CONVERT(date,[Datetime],106)
```

Comment: you should add the CONVERT(date, ...) in the SELECT.

Comment: in this method i sum by days and not 24th and in case i will have another row in the data: A 1/3/2011 4:00:00 you will get another row in the output for A and i expect it to be summed to the value appeared 24 hours ago

Comment: @AvishyS When you change date it change of 24 hours so it is display next row

Comment: actually it didn't work i used the same data as above with another row of 'A','2011-01-03 4:00:00',1  - i expected to get: A,2368; B,2042; A,3; B,549 but i got A,2368; B,2042; A,2; B,549; A,1 with your solution

Answer (score 1):

original:

```
SELECT
      name
    , CAST([DateTime] AS date) AS [Date]
    , SUM(value)
FROM YourTable
WHERE [DateTime] >= '20110101'
      AND [DateTime] < '20120101'
GROUP BY
      name
    , CAST([DateTime] AS date)
```

in response to this comment:

- not a calendar day but 24h - so if there is value in 23:00 i expect
  it to be summed with the value at 1:00 on the day after

You want to "push" the stored data by 2 hours, so do that through **DATEADD(hour,2,[DateTime])** and you an adjust the unit and amount if needed.

```
SELECT
      name
    , CAST( DATEADD(hour,2,[DateTime]) AS date) AS [Date]
    , SUM(value)
FROM YourTable
WHERE [DateTime] >= '20110101'
      AND [DateTime] < '20120101'
GROUP BY
      name
    , CAST( DATEADD(hour,2,[DateTime]) AS date)
```

Note: If you are trying to counteract the effect of timezones using a constant 2 hour adjustment will not always be accurate if you have "daylight saving time" periods. For this it MIGHT be worth doing something like this:

```
DECLARE @tzadjust AS INT = DATEDIFF(minute,getutcdate(),getdate())

SELECT
      name
    , CAST( DATEADD(minute,@tzadjust,[DateTime]) AS date) AS [Date]
    , SUM(value)
FROM YourTable
WHERE [DateTime] >= '20110101'
      AND [DateTime] < '20120101'
GROUP BY
      name
    , CAST( DATEADD(minute,@tzadjust,[DateTime]) AS date)
```

You can check the difference by:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(minute,getutcdate(),getdate())
```